# How to get the name of the altered table in a Postgres event trigger?

Tags: postgresql, ddl, triggers

in a `postgres` database, have table `base1` that is the base table for view `view1`.

if a column in `base1` is created, dropped or renamed, I would like to recreate the view `view1` with a ddl trigger.

```
create event trigger base1_views
   on ddl_command_end
   when tag in( 'ALTER TABLE' )
   execute procedure base1_views_fn();

create function base1_views_fn() returns void as $$
declare
  buf varchar;
begin
  -- is table being altered = 'base'?
  -- add, drop or renaming a column?
  buf = 'drop view view1';
  execute buf;
  buf = 'create view view1 as select * from base1 where ...';
  execute buf;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

within the function `base1_views_fn()`, how do we obtain the table name and whether we are changing columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same issue addressed here: [How to get SQL text from Postgres event trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488228)

bottom line, as of now, wait until more features are added to EVENT TRIGGER in future releases

Answer (score 2):

The variables available to plpgsql in a trigger are defined here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-EVENT-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

What I can't tell from the text is how many 'event' variables there are.  Certainly there are two:

```
TG_EVENT
Data type text; a string representing the event the trigger is fired for.

TG_TAG
Data type text; variable that contains the command tag for which the trigger is fired.
```

You can print these in your function to see if they contain the table information you are looking for.  The documentation shows a bunch of other variables that are for regular events.  I don't know if those will help, but, perhaps TG_TABLE_NAME is set?

Comment: tag is ALTER TABLE. tg_table_name does not exist. if the original query could be seen that would expose everything, but cannot see that either.

Comment: the event triggers are pretty new. does TG_EVENT have anything useful in it?  I use views / functions everywhere in postgres.  I put them in a separate schema, then *every* time there is a base schema change I drop the schema which contains all of the functions/views/etc cascade. I make the base table changes, then I recreate all of the functions/views/etc.  You can do this inside a transaction, which insulates (a little) the hiccup that may be seen by active users. You could do the same thing for a single table.

Comment: see comments here: stackoverflow.com/questions/23488228/how-to-get-sql-text-from-postgres-event-trigger