# How to get SQL text from Postgres event trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

In a pgsql event trigger on tag ALTER TABLE, I wish to know which table is being altered.

The pg variables do not cover this, nor do the variables exposed by GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS.

With variables available, is there any way within the trigger function itself to see the text of the SQL command responsible for initiating the function.

for example, if

```
ALTER TABLE base1 ADD COLUMN col1 int;
```

were responsible for calling the event trigger, is there any way within the event trigger to see then `ALTER TABLE base1 ADD COLUMN col1 int` text itself?

Comment: `SELECT current_query()`. But it'll only show the *top level* query, which isn't necessarily what fired the event trigger - say, if you did an `ALTER TABLE` with a PL/PgSQL function. Event triggers will be extended to add much more information about the command, but are currently very limited in 9.3/9.4 .

Comment: @CraigRinger - thanks. looking forward to extensions!

Comment: If you write an event trigger in C, you have also the parse tree of the command. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/event-trigger-interface.html Surely not the best approach to rely on that, but its something until this feature is extended.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Starting from PostgreSQL 9.5, function [`pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-event-triggers.html) is available for `ddl_command_end` event triggers. Using the `TAG` filter, it may be used for processing any ALTERed table. `object_identity` (or `objid`) may be used to solve the original problem of knowing which table has been ALTERed. As for getting the complete command, it is available, too, but it is of an internal type `pg_ddl_command`.

```
CREATE TABLE t (n INT);

CREATE FUNCTION notice_event() RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
DECLARE r RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'caught % event on %', r.command_tag, r.object_identity;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER tr_notice_alter_table
  ON ddl_command_end WHEN TAG IN ('ALTER TABLE')
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE notice_event();

ALTER TABLE t ADD c CHAR;
```

outputs:
`NOTICE:  caught ALTER TABLE event on public.t`

Comment: how to grab some more data than `tg_tag` and `tg_event` in case of `ddl_command_start`?

Comment: Is there a way to get the actual SQL that was executed? `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()` returns one column `command`  but it seems the content is not accessible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you can use current_query() to catch it.

Comment: So far the best answer I have found is that there isn't actually any way to use the `command` column. It appears to be something like an incomplete implementation according to this thread: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20190712222343.GA26924%40alvherre.pgsql

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the `command` column is basically a dead end, unless you are capable of making your own c-function to process the data. For everyone else, this solution seems to work:

1. Install the `pgddl` extension https://github.com/lacanoid/pgddl
2. Use something like `SELECT ddlx_create(objid) FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()` as the ddl text for each object.

I've tested it and it works just about exactly what I would hope for.