# Is there a way to monitor all ddl scripts in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ddl-trigger

I'm trying to save all ddl scripts that runs on the database in a table. In SQL Server this could be achieved by setting a DDL Trigger on the database and getting the scripts from the EVENT_DATA object in the trigger context. So far, I haven't found a way do the same thing in PostgreSQL. 
Is it even possible?

Comment: This might point you a direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488228/how-to-get-sql-text-from-postgres-event-trigger

Comment: or just configure: `log_statement='ddl';`

Comment: This might be better asked on the DBA Stack Exchange, a sister site of Stack Overflow.