# How to get sql query from pg_ddl_command

Tags: postgresql, eventtrigger

How can I parse the `pg_ddl_command` field in the `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands` function in the scope of ddl command end event trigger in postgres 10+?

Comment: It's only possible with a C function, unfortunately.  See https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/commands/event_trigger.c

Comment: Is there any example where someone managed to do this?

Comment: I haven't seen one, but I'd be curious to see if it you do find or create one.  It could be a worthwhile extension...

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488228/how-to-get-sql-text-from-postgres-event-trigger). Use current_query() to get the currently executing command.