# Event trigger to change owner on CREATE

Tags: postgresql, eventtrigger

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL event trigger, that fires whenever a user creates anything (table, view, function, sequence...) and sets the owner of this newly created thing to a certain role.

So far I have the even trigger itself, that fires on any CREATE command:

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER setOwnerToMyRole ON ddl_command_end
WHEN tg_tag LIKE 'CREATE%'
EXECUTE PROCEDURE setOwnerToMyRole();
```

But I am having problems with the function itself:

```
CREATE FUNCTION setOwnerToMyRole() RETURNS event_trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$ BEGIN
    ALTER <type> <name> OWNER TO myRole 
END; $$;
```

How do I get the type (as in table, view, etc.) and how do i get the name of the newly created thing?

---

edit:
Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454339/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-altered-table-in-a-postgres-event-trigger) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488228/how-to-get-sql-text-from-postgres-event-trigger) and of course [CREATE EVENT TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html) and [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html), this is currently not really possible :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess, I should answer this question properly and not just in an edit:
What I want is currently not possible. Perhaps a future update to Postgres will add more functionality to eventtriggers.

Sources:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html
- [How to get the name of the altered table in a Postgres event trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454339/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-altered-table-in-a-postgres-event-trigger)
- [How to get SQL text from Postgres event trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488228/how-to-get-sql-text-from-postgres-event-trigger)

Comment: can you elaborate more on why? It's not clear why this isn't the case and people keep saying it *should* be possible. I need to implement something like this. Even if you don't get the text you need from the event itself, the fact there is a `CREATE` event could be a trigger to query `pg_tables` for any objects not owned by the target role and then updated with an `ALTER TABLE <new_table> OWNER TO my_role`. Did you try anything like that?

Answer (score 3):

This works pretty well for me, although it's a little broader net than needed. It is based on code at https://blog.hagander.net/setting-owner-at-create-table-237/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_create_set_owner()
 RETURNS event_trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  obj record;
BEGIN
  -- postgresql 9.5 or later:
  -- FOR obj in SELECT table_name FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() WHERE command_tag='CREATE TABLE'
  FOR obj IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE tableowner = current_user LOOP
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s OWNER TO my_group', obj.tablename);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER trg_create_set_owner
 ON ddl_command_end
 WHEN tag IN ('CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE AS')
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_create_set_owner();
```