# How to get LAST_DDL_TIME information(as in Oracle dba_all_objects) at Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, ddl, postgresql-10

Postgresql database version is :

```
PostgreSQL 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
```

Comment: Not possible. Postgres does not store that information

Comment: I just want to be sure about new version(10+) also doesn't store that information or not. The questions and answers you added to my question are old. The newest one is 4 year old. It is possible to have this information store property added in this time right? Is this answers valid for versions 10+?

Comment: Yes that's still the case, otherwise I wouldn't have closed that question

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: By the way there is an alternative way to get this information as mentioned in this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454339/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-altered-table-in-a-postgres-event-trigger